# I have ? (Question mark) on update statement genertaed by sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I wanna update my model by sequlize with below code:

```
                    let playUrl = 'http://example.com/test-23';
                     modelClass.update({play_url: playUrl}
                        ,{
                            
                            where :{
                                id:{
                                    [Op.eq]:800
                                }
        
                        }});
```

But finally Sequlize generate this for me:

```
  UPDATE `md_song` SET `play_url`=? WHERE `id` = 800
```

Do you know why it don't pass as parameter ??

Comment: The thing is that it prepare the values that comes from "outside" just so it wont have any bad code that can for instance delete all you db.

Comment: @Talg123 what do you mean from outside? You mean I can't pass paramter as value ?

Comment: It's a parameterised query. Nothing special about it.

Comment: @Bergi ok, but why sequelize don;t pass nothing?

Comment: What makes you think that no value was passed for the parameter? How did you even find the generated SQL query? How is your `modelClass` configured, how does your database connection look? (I had to assume it's MySQL, there might be others using the same syntax)